# How to put a line under a word and controle marging of an element CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm facing two issues please,

first I want to controle width of a line under a word, could you tell me please how can I achieve this result please,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwKxl.png)
I tries to put `text-decoration: underline;` but it gives a line under the whole word.
the second problem, I want to put a container over a container, the first one with an image and the second one with a form, when I open in:
tablette :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNN19.png)
it gives the expected result, but when I open in the browser it gives this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZlF9.png)
as you see the image is pushed on the left.
what I'm looking for , is I want the image to be displayed always at the right of the screen like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNN19.png)

css of the first container :

```
background: #F8F8F8;
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 35px;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
```

css of the container contains the image :

```
height: 350px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
```

css of the first container :

```
background: #F8F8F8;
margin-right: 40px;
padding: 35px;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
```

css of the container contains the image :

```
height: 350px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first thing:

HTML:

```
<span class="underlined-text">Creez Vorte Compe</span>
```

CSS:

```
.underlined-text {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.underlined-text::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%; /* Change this to achieve what you want to achieve */
}
```

As for your second problem, I don't really get what's the problem but one possible solution is specifying a width for divs. This will make sure that the divs don't take all available space.

Comment: thanks, it works, could you tell me please How can I push the line to the right please,I tries marging-left:2px; but it did not work

Comment: Change the value of the left property i.e., if you want to push the line to right 2px, change the value of left to 2px